# Transfer of emails from an OWA account to a file on a storage device (e.g. USB stick)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

I urgently need to transfer the OWA emails already existing in an OWA account into a file that I can store on a external device (e.g.  a USB stick), as the OWA account will very shortly be deleted. There are hundreds of emails to be
transferred.

Subsequently I wish to read the emails stored on the external device.

To achieve the above goal, I have been advised by Microsoft to first add the OWA account to a desktop version of Outlook.

I am confused about what happens when I add the OWA account to Outlook. I am assuming that the OWA account is actually an Exchange account.

Having added the OWA account, can I then Export the OWA emails directly to a .pst file and then store the .pst file on a USB stick ?

Or is a .ost file first created, which I then have to convert 
to a .pst file ? I understand the .ost to .pst conversion can be done manually (using the Archive option in Outlook) or by using commercially available software.

Comment: You basically got it right. OWA is part of Exchange. By configuring it in outlook, it is downloaded as .ost (caching mode). You will want to set it to work online though. Once done, export to .pst and you can then put that on a stick.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. I'm not sure what you mean by 'You will want to set it to work online '. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: When you configure an account in Office, by default it configures this with Cache turned on. This means you have to wait for all mail to download before you can export, or you will simply not export everything. If you go to advanced settings, when configuring the email, you can specify that you do not want to use caching, but instead work online. By doing so, when you export, it will force everything to be downloaded and exported.